# Hide fields in forms, when the form is printed

Tags: javascript, forms, adobe, acrobat

I have an Adobe Acrobat Form and there are fields that are useful, while it is digital, but i want them to be hidden when it is printed out.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: If acrobat supports CSS, the CSS rule @media print https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: unfortunately acrobat doesnt support CSS

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer:

Under general Options -> form field you can set it to "visible, but dont print"